# Delimiters in C

Tags: c, delimiter

In C, I'm trying to write a program that tokenizes the content of my input.txt file. I'm trying to write a delimiter that assumes that any character except alphabetical characters, dash, and the apostrophe character is considered to be a delimiter that separates words. Can anybody give me an idea of how to write this delimiter?

```
 char * delimitier = ....
 char *token = (char *) malloc(100);

 FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
 if (file != NULL) {
     while (fgets(token, 100, file) != NULL) {
         strtok(token, delimiter);
         insertWord(token);
     }
     fclose(file);
 }
```

Comment: Didn't [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66960914/use-a-specific-delimiter-in-c) help? How is this question different from that one? Please don't repost the same question over and over, *edit* your existing question to improve it instead.

Comment: That would be all characters from 32 to 255 except alphabetical characters, dash, and the apostrophe character. You can generate this with 4-5 lines of code: `for (char ch = 33; ch <=255; ch++) {...}` you can figure out this yourself. That's pretty simple, but it's kind of a hack. See comment just below this one.

Comment: And to quote a comment from your previous question: "If you're trying to create a delimiter string to use with `strtok`, then don't." Create a brand new function which checks if a character is a "delimiter" and then create a function which "splits" your string using the "is delimiter" function.

Comment: I would not use `strtok` for this.

Comment: And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: BTW: your usage of `strtok` is wrong. Read again it's documentation and look up one of the numerous samples that show how `strtok` is used.